# XCTest does not link iOS frameworks

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, xctest, xcrun

I'm running iOS simulator unit tests on the command line using `xctest`. First I build the target:

```
xcodebuild -project "build/MyApp.xcodeproj" -target "MyApp Unit Tests" -configuration "Debug" -sdk "iphonesimulator" build
```

And then run `xctest` on the test bundle:

```
xcrun xctest "build/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp Unit Tests.xctest"
```

This works fine, and can link frameworks that are in /System/Library/Frameworks like Security. But `xctest` breaks as soon as I add an iOS SDK framework like MobileCoreServices, giving me:

```
Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
```

The unit tests run fine in Xcode, and the unit test target includes `$(PLATFORM_DIR)/Developer/Library/Frameworks` in its Frameworks Search Paths.

Anybody know the right way to make `xctest` find iOS frameworks?

Answer (score 0):

The test target needs to be able to look for frameworks in the built product of MyApp. You should add a framework search path to the test target:

```
$(CONFIGURATION_TEMP_DIR)/MyApp.build/DerivedSources
```